# How to generate pub and pubkey in json string format using command solana-keygen grind

Tags: solana-cli, solana-keygen

How to generate pub and pubkey in json string format using command solana-keygen grind,solana-keygen command generate and puts in json file, that i want to avoid

Comment: Or can we grind these address in browser itself, utilising user hardware capabilities using webworker or something?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is correctly phrased. Do you want to grind a public key and view its private key as integer array on command line instead of it saving in a JSON file?

Comment: @SyedAabisAkhtar yes correct want to just view the pub and private key instead of writting them in json file

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get the JSON array to print to stdout, but you can run:

```
$ solana-keygen grind --use-mnemonic --starts-with <PREFIX>:1 --no-outfile --no-bip39-passphrase
```

Which outputs:

```
Searching with 20 threads for:
        1 pubkey that starts with '...' and ends with ''
======================================================================
Found matching key ...

Save this seed phrase to recover your new keypair:
....
======================================================================
```

PRs on keygen are always welcome though! You can find the source code at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/tree/master/keygen